# BIRT report timezone

Tags: birt

We are using BIRT for reporting in our application. When we tested the reports on local end, it was working as expected. Then we deployed the application on test server where OS is ubuntu and we are using mysql as our database server. Now the timezone of both OS and mysql are set to IST. But when we generate the report, it shows date/time before 5:30 hours i.e. GMT time. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the problem is that you are viewing the report in other timezone than the server, you can pass the paramenter __timezone to the viewer and the dates will render in that time zone.

Answer (score 0):

bind the date/time to the data element and right click the element and go to properties and select the format data time .

then select your local as you want

You can use lable also and use `<value-of format="yyyy-MM-dd">new Date()</value-of>`

Or rigth click on your label/element and apply new style with your format of date time

Comment: ty for your quick reply. I could change the date-format, but the date is not proper, reports are showing date in GMT. How can I make report to show dates in IST?